# Translate from logical expression to regular expression

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a type of exercise in which I want to translate a formal logical expression to regular expression. Now my question is, is there a set of rules which I can learn so I will be able to do this types of exercises or is just intuitive? Can you provide me some textbooks, video tutorial, etc from which I could learn?
For example I have this expresion : 
$$ (\forall \mathbb{M})(\mathbb{M}\subset A\Rightarrow ((\exists x) x \in A \wedge (\forall m) (m\in \mathbb{M} \Rightarrow m\leqslant x ) \Rightarrow ((\forall \mathbb{N})(\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{M}\Rightarrow(\exists x) x\in A \wedge (\forall n)(n\in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow n\leqslant x))))) $$
Are there any rules I have to apply to this? And by the way what is that expression saying?
Thank you!

Comment: @jon-mark-perry I do not see the connection with this question.

Comment: Is your formula a MSO-formula to be interpreted on finite words? Is $A$ interpreted as the domain $\{1, \dotsm, |u|\}$ associated to a word $u$?